# can i use DefaultRouter with CreateAPIView in django rest?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

when I try to add my CreateAPIView to router.register it rise TypeError exception:

```
  File "/home/denys/.virtualenvs/buddha_test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 281, in get_urls
    view = viewset.as_view(mapping, **route.initkwargs)
TypeError: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

But if I add url directly to urlpatterns it works!
The resone is that I whant to see link in API Root:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yH8t.png)

So quation is can I write something like this:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'clients-list', views.ClientList)
router.register(r'managers-list', views.ManagerList)
router.register(r'clients', views.CleintCreate, base_name='create')


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),

]
```

views.py

```
from .models import Client, Manager
from .serializers import ClientSerializer, ManagerSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route

class ClientList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer


class ManagerList(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
# 
    queryset = Manager.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ManagerSerializer


class CleintCreate(CreateAPIView):

    model = Client
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of implementing `CreateAPIView`, you can create `GenericViewSet` and also inherit `CreateModelMixin`:

`views.py`:

```
# ...

class ClientCreate(CreateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    model = Client
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

And then in your `urls.py` it's just the same:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from rest_framework import routers

from . import views


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'clients-list', views.ClientList)
router.register(r'managers-list', views.ManagerList)
router.register(r'clients', views.ClientCreate, base_name='create')


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Thx, so in general DefultRouter work only with any kinds of ViewSet?

Comment: @DenysGurin Yes. As the docs say: **"There are two mandatory arguments to the `register()` method: `prefix` and `viewset`."**